# server 12.04 boot dhcp, can not find hard disk

Tags: 12.04, server, boot, broadcom, dhcp

I am trying to set up ubuntu server 12.04 LTS on my old Dell desktop for a LAMP home testing server.  The install went fine, but when I start up, I do not see the the grub boot loader (which i re-installed in recovery mode).

I flagged '/dev/sda5' as my bootable partition, but it looks like it is still trying to boot from the network?  It is plugged directly to my router via ethernet.

I was reluctant to post because I feel like this is a stupid question, but I am still learning, so any help setting up this LAMP server is greatly appreciated!

THANKS!

"Screenshots":

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zB9n.jpg
~2-5 minutes, it tries to boot from DHCP?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2vDz.jpg
PXE-E53: No bootfile name recieved.
Does not find my bootable partition.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a hardware problem where the computer's BIOS does not see GRUB in `/dev/sda` and therefore defaults to network. This may be fixed by a few things:

1. Ensure GRUB is on `/dev/sda`. If you installed it to `/dev/sda1`,  some BIOS's hate that.
2. Check that your hard disk is securely attached by its cable and getting power. Ensure your BIOS is set to try it before anything else, especially `Network`.
3. Ensure your hard disk does not have bad sectors

Should you need more info, please comment. When I have time tomorrow morning, I will add more detailed instructions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I reinstalled and now I have /dev/sda with a 2GB swap partition.  /dev/sda is flagged bootable.

Same problem...
I cannot see a hard disk when i try to set the boot order.  I did notice for the Dell Dimension 2350, there is a bios A02, so I will try upgrading to that tomorrow (I am on A00).